# Проблемы с паком при билде unity appodeal

Tags: unity3d, ads

Я установил пак Appodeal и попытался скомпилировать, все правильно - без пака компилируется. А вот ошибка -[image: скриншот ошибки]

[image: скриншот вынесенных ошибок в консоле]
Я пытался найти ответ и я то ли не могу найти, то ли если нахожу, то я не понимаю, что нужно то делать и в чем вопще ошибка. Буду рад помощи!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша проблема заключается в том, что вы превысили лимит в 64к нативных Android методов. Корни этой проблемы заключаются в нативных плагинах, судя по всему в java коде плагина Appodeal большое число методов. До того, как вы интегрировали его себе в проект вы влезали в лимит, а с ним уже нет (на первом скриншоте видно, что у вас более 65536 методов).

Подробней о вашей проблеме вы можете почитать [тут с возможным решением](https://habr.com/post/314416/) или [тут с точки зрения чистого Android без unity](https://habr.com/post/230665/), а возможным решением будет использовать Multidex или провести ревизию нативных плагинов  в проекте, возможно вы найдете неиспользуемые, которые сможете удалить, тем самым уменьшив число нативных методов в проекте.